# Is there a name for this type of sentence construction?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, construction

"He was a thin leathery man with colorless eyes, so colorless that light did not reflect his eyes". What kind of construction is that? I usually see similar sentences being split into two sentences.

Answer (score 1):

As it is a sentence from Harper Lee's magnificent novel *To Kill a Mockingbird*, the construction would be termed *brilliant* or something like that.

Coming from the pen of a mere mortal, the sentence would be called *stringy* or *strung together.*

What makes this sentence work so well is the appositive clause to the first *colorless* that at once overstates the adjective and artfully moves the word "eyes" and avoids a possibly anticlimactic prepositional phrase at the end.

(The implied phrasing is "He was a thin leathery man with colorless eyes, [eyes] so colorless that light did not reflect [in them]."

(This is marvelous literary work, but as the Latin proverb says, *quot licet iovi, non licet bovi* - What Jove may do is forbidden to the ox. We the lowly might be marked amiss for similar things.)

Comment: Harper Lee has been rightly acclaimed for much - including her undoubted understanding of the society which she reproduces, her characters etc. But having read *Mockingbird* within the last year, I would certainly not compliment her for her syntax nor her eloquence. Deeply insightful, sensitive and important work that it is, the novel is not well written.